# Zend Framework 2 – can't get around ServiceNotFoundException

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

Today I bought a book to learn the Zend Framework 2. Having started with the skeleton Application & skeleton module, I made good progress, until database interaction started. Now every time I want to do something with the database, I get the following exception:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException  

File: /Applications/AMPPS/www/myproject/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529  

Message:  
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter
```

Possible reasons for this could be incorrect database details, but having used the same credentials for other projects, I know they are correct (local development).

My `global.php` looks like this – I can't see any errors:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=mydatabasename;host=localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'mysql',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
        'service_manager' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Following the stacktrace, the error must be in the beginning of this method:

```
protected function createUser(array $data)
    {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();

        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User);
        $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

        $user = new User();
        $user->exchangeArray($data);
        $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);
        $userTable->saveUser($user);
        return true;
    }
```

But again, I can't see any error here, which leaves me a bit puzzled. I guess the error is more than just a typo.

The class that method is located in uses the following Zend Framework 2 components (besides self written ones):

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
```

Do I need to add something here, maybe to be able to use the `getServiceLocator()` method? I don't know there that method is located.

Do you have anymore ideas what could cause this exception? I am using Zend Framework 2.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put the `service_manager` key as a subset to `db`. This is wrong.

The `service_manager` key needs to be top level.

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=mydatabasename;host=localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'mysql',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'
        )
    )
);
```